# PyCharm Uninstall unsucessful: "Uninstall hasn't detected folder of PyCharm Installation"

Tags: pycharm, uninstallation

My build of Pycharm Professional (2022.1.4) is unable to uninstall itself via:

- The windows settings uninstall utility
- Running uninstall.exe in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.4\bin`

I'm provided with a pop-up message reading:

```
Uninstall hasn't detected folder of PyCharm Installation. Probably Uninstall.exe was moved from the installation folder.
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Original credit for this solution goes to the JetBrains youtrack user Benjamin Hutchensen on this [thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35047). I'm creating a SO post for longevity/visibility.

This issue is caused by a missing file in your PyCharm Installation. To create this file, open powershell with adminsitrator privledges and execute the following powershell commands to create an empty file in that location with the appropriate name:

```
 1.  cd 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.4\bin'
 2.  New-Item -Path 'IdeaWin64.dll' -ItemType File
```

After this approach, I was able to successfully uninstall my PyCharm installation.

Comment: FYI this works for Goland too

Comment: worth to note - PowerShell must be executed with elevated (administrator) privileges.

Comment: FYI Worked for intelliJ IDEA community AND ultimate versions (java) as well... for anyone who has also searched for hours with no success. 
I needed to run the uninstall.exe in the bin folder as an administrator. The uninstall.exe outside of bin didn't work.

Comment: Worked with Jetbrains Rider 2023.2 EAP2 after having the same problem.

Comment: This did not work or make any difference for me for PyCharm 2022.1.3. PowerShell was run elevated.

Comment: This also works with WebStorm, thanks for copying this here!

Comment: Also works for IntelliJ IDEA. I just created an empty file IdeaWin64.dll in the bin directory with the cygwin "touch" command in an administrative command prompt.

Comment: I am trying to do this for IntelliJ IDEA, but I get a "File already exists" message and I can't proceed.

Comment: Worked perfectly for IntelliJ Ultimate. The problem was that I had a original "classical" instalation (downloaded the ide, installed) and after a time I switched to JetBrains ToolBox (bad idea), creating a sort of secondary installations on User/AppData

Comment: Worked for an old PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1 after I had installed the latest licensed version of PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for an older version of CLion.

Comment: I tried to do this to uninstall Rider v2023.3.1. But it did not work. And followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77165547/7328702) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**I have found the solution it was so problematic so to git rid out of this you can simply so the following stuffs:**

1. Simple install new version of PyCharm either community version or professional version.
2. setup and run
3. Now go to following location

> 'C/Program Files/JetBrains/newer version folder/bin

1. Now copy the uninstall from newer version to older version bin folder and simply replace it

now enjoy!! you can uninstall the program

Comment: This worked for me to uninstall Rider.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, PyCharm 2022.1.3 is shown in the list of installed software (and offered to uninstall by newer PyCharm installers). But in `C:\Program Files`, I only have a `PyCharm 2022.1.1` folder and some folders for older versions. Neither of these show up in the list of installed software. Also, none of these folders contains an "uninstall.exe", and copying an "uninstall.exe" from a later version did not do the trick, either (same error message).

I ended up just deleting the entry for the old PyCharm version from the registry. If you search for "PyCharm", you will find an entry under a key named "uninstall" referring to the old version. Of course, I also deleted all the old folders.

Answer (score -2):

I implemented the solution provided by @Carter but it didn't worked for me. So instead i did this

1. Download Lastest Version of PyCharm (2023.1 in mycase)
2. Install It and Launch Pycharm with current verison that you installed (Note: It PC shows two version like previous and current to use.)
3. Now Delete the 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.3' Folder (Note: Check the version of Old PyCharm. In my case it was PyCharm 2022.1.3)
4. The Delete the Luncher 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3'
5. Now Restart the PC and start using PyCharm it will work fine.

Hope this solution will work you as well.

Comment: Note that the installer of a newer version also fails to uninstall the older version with the same error message. Deleting a folder of course always works, but it does not remove the old version from the list of installed software.