# IntelliJ IDEA won't uninstall

Tags: intellij-idea, uninstallation

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2
Windows 10

I tried uninstalling IntelliJ from the control panel but was not able to do so and there was this popup which said -

```
Uninstall hasn't detected folder of IntelliJ Installation. Probably Uninstall.exe was moved from the installation folder.
```

I updated the IDE, tried restarting it, and even tried restarting my system.

The problem persists and I get the same popup.

Answer (score 4):

I referred to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75536394/pycharm-uninstall-unsucessful-uninstall-hasnt-detected-folder-of-pycharm-inst) and was able to solve my problem in this way -

This happened because `IdeaWin64.dll` file was missing from the `bin` folder where IntelliJ was installed.

The installation by default takes place in - `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2`

The solution is to create the required file in the bin folder and then proceed to uninstall from the control panel.

Follow these steps -

1. Open command prompt in administrator mode.
2. Navigate to your bin folder inside the installation folder, for me the path looked like this - `cd 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin'`
3. Create the dll file - `cd .>IdeaWin64.dll`
4. Close the control panel, go to your control panel and now uninstall IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: this was still relevant when updating to 2023.3.4 - file `IdeaWin64.dll` was missing in `bin`, adding a dummy file with that name helped